# 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference

Tags: android

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String
>   android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference

I know this question ask here many time but i cant able to solve this 
i am  new in android an i am can't able to solve this problem

i want to click on card view and start new activity 
i write code for this but problem is this error come when i hit cardview

please tell me how to solve this

following is my code

Maia activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private List<Data> movieList = new ArrayList<>();
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private MoviesAdapter  mAdapter;
private Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mAdapter = new MoviesAdapter(movieList,context) ;
    context = getApplicationContext();

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    prepareMovieData();
}

private void prepareMovieData() {

    Data data = new Data("MadMax");
    movieList.add(data);

    data = new Data("MadMax1");
    movieList.add(data);

    data = new Data("MadMax2");
    movieList.add(data);

    data = new Data("MadMax3");
    movieList.add(data);

    data = new Data("MadMax4");
    movieList.add(data);

    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

Adapter

```
public class MoviesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MoviesAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private List<Data> moviesList;
private Context context;

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.single_row_layout, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView title;

    public View view;
    public MyViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);

        view = v;
        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
    }
}

public MoviesAdapter(List<Data> moviesList,Context context) {

    this.moviesList = moviesList;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder,int position) {

    Data data = moviesList.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(data.getTitle());

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context,Parts.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return moviesList.size();
}
}
```

Logcat

> 02-25 18:05:43.121 11930-11930/com.example.owner.theconstitutionofindia E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                             Process: com.example.owner.theconstitutionofindia, PID: 11930
>                                                                                             java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null
>   object reference
>                                                                                                 at android.content.ComponentName.(ComponentName.java:77)
>                                                                                                 at android.content.Intent.(Intent.java:4170)
>                                                                                                 at
>   com.example.owner.theconstitutionofindia.MoviesAdapter$1.onClick(MoviesAdapter.java:86)
>                                                                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4785)
>                                                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19884)
>                                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
>                                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                                 at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
>                                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)

please tell me how to solve this problem and how to start new activity through card view.

Comment: first check if both file in same package and also pass activity to adapter too.

Comment: thanks for you answer its working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
context=MainActivity.this
mAdapter = new MoviesAdapter(movieList,context) ;
```

Comment: once context is initialize replace all entrance of getApplicationContext with context

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
mAdapter = new MoviesAdapter(movieList,context) ;
context = getApplicationContext();
```

you are using `context` before initializing it.
Make it

```
context = getApplicationContext();
mAdapter = new MoviesAdapter(movieList,context) ;
```

Also make

```
context = getApplicationContext();
```

to

```
context = MainActivity.this;
```

Answer (score 0):

first check if both file in same package and also pass activity to adapter too. don't just pass context and cast it to activity.

```
public MoviesAdapter(List<Data> moviesList,Context context, Activity activity) {
this.moviesList = moviesList;
this.context = context;
this,activity = activity;
}
```

this approach is not working always;

```
context = ActivityName.this;
```